# How to create all possible subsets for vector with 55 elements in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector with 55 elements.  I am trying to obtain all possible subsets of this vector, which should be 55! = 1.2696403e+73 possible combinations...  I am currently trying to use `set_power()` from the `sets` package, which should return a set of all the possible subsets.  However, I'm concerned that R cannot handle this huge amount of possible combinations, since I believe there is a limit of around 2 billion in R.  Does anyone have any ideas for a way I could parse this out into manageable chunks?

Comment: Just wondering, what's the use case that causes you to try and do this?

Comment: This is a classic [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). There's about 10^68 atoms in our galaxy. All the computers in the world cannot hold 10^73 sets. So why do you think you need all of these sets? Would it suffice to sample randomly from them, which is very doable?

Comment: Hi Vvdl, this will sound crazy...  I have a list of 55 numbers, and someone once used these 55 numbers to calculate an average value.  Their calculated average has become important, but it's unclear how they calculated their average, and they no longer have the calculations.  So, my idea was to calculate the average (mean or median) for all of the possible combinations of those 55 numbers, to see if I can figure out what data they actually used in the calculations.  And no, unfortunately it wasn't just an average using all 55 numbers. :(

Comment: How sure are you that they calculated an average of some subset of that data vs, say, doing a weighted average or a geometric mean or a harmonic mean or... And if you think they did do a straight-up average of a subset, is there really no way to guess what elements might have been left out? Maybe they did a trimmed mean dropping the highest and lowest X% (which would be easy to check for different values of X).

Comment: Hi Gregor Thomas, thank you very much for your replies!  I honestly have no idea how they arrived at their final number - I've asked the person who did it, and they were unable to remember, and cannot locate the original calculations.  And I don't know what elements might have been left out.  So I was just trying to start with a mean...  If you have any suggestions for ways to randomly sample, or any other ideas, I'd be all ears!

Comment: First all the sets is not 55! but rather 2^55-1 number of sets. Also as  @GregorThomas indicated, this is an XY problem.

Comment: @GregorThomas is right that you'll have to find some way to constrain the problem. Do you at least know if the person kicked out just a couple values? e.g., there are only 55 sets of 54 elements and 1484 sets of 53 elements...

Comment: Also the mean is a summary of the data. You cannot recover the data. eg `-2,-1,0,1,2,-10,10` . Lets say the mean is 0, did they use `-2,2`? `-2,-1,1,2`? `-2,-1,0,1,2` etc?? You note that all those combinations have a mean of 0. many more combinations will have mean of 0, eg `-10,10`

Comment: Onyambu has an excellent point, 2^55 is about 3.6*10^16, which is **much** more manageable.  If each combination can be stored in 8 bytes, then that's about 288 Petabytes of storage needed. It will take some engineering to set it up, but you could store that on AWS S3 for about $9,200 per minute.

Comment: Hi zephryl, thanks for your reply.  I don't know if they kicked out any data, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi onyambu, thank you for pointing out the number of sets is 2^55, not 55! as I typed above. :)  It is still way to big as you are all pointing out.

Comment: I'd start with trimmed mean, `sapply(1:20 / 55, \(x) mean(your_vector, trim = x))` will calculate trimmed means omitting 1 through 20 values from each end.

Comment: (Also have you considered the possibility that the number you're trying to replicate is just a typo?)

Comment: So this is a data forensics problem where you have a mean (could only be a median if it matches one of the numbers or is at the midpoint of two successive #s) and want to know what subset of those 55 numbers would have that mean? This is more achievable by brute force if the number of excluded #s is small -- there are only 55 combinations excluding one, 2,970 excluding two, etc. There are probably also more clever analytic optimization approaches that look at the mean and discern what elements must be included.

Comment: Thanks Gregor for the suggestion about trimmed mean, will give that a shot